# How to know about updated framework 4.8 framework in Asp.net v4.0.30xxxxxxx version in Framework64 folder and IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, .net-framework-version

I am using windows 2008 R2 server and I successfully installed Microsoft .Net FrameWork 4.8 through web installer in the server 2008 R2 for update the .Net Framework after that I went folder  Framework64/v4.0.30xxxxxxx but I did not find any file replaced in that folder. I ordered the folder through modified date then only two logs files are showing at the top with current year 2020 others files including system.dll are 2019 year. How to know my applications running in IIS 7 Application Pools with latest 4.8 .Net Framework version because in IIS also show same v4.0.30xxxxxxx version in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Check the official document to query the installed DotNET framework version.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed
Here is my registry result. Therefore, I have installed the DotNET Framework4.8 (^.^)
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.